# Android: change backgroundcolor of items in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I would like to create a list of notes with a due date. If the due date is reached, the background color should change.

I tried to manage the items in an ArrayAdapter and bind the adapter to the listview of the listview activity.

I found the methodes getChildCount() and getHeaderViewsCount() but both return 0.

Here is the code I tried:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mStringList));
for (int i = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition(); i < lv.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = lv.getChildAt(i);
            Log.d("MyActivity", String.valueOf(v.getId()));
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
```

As getFirstVisiblePosition returns 0 and getChildCount returns 0 the loop will never be entered.

Are these the correct methods for accessing the child-elements of a listview?

Comment: use custom `listview` Adapter and apply your conditions in `getView()` method

Comment: you have to implement the custom adapter for the listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your background color should be set to one color or the other in the getView method of your adapter, and you should just call notifyDataSetChanged on your adapter to request a refresh of your elements.

Answer (score 0):

should be "Custom ListView" , see [here](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/04/android-listview-background-row-style.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom adapter, then in the getView you can check your row content and adjust the colour accordingly.

Here's a a good tutorial:
http://webdeveloperpadawan.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/android-listview-with-differing-rows.html

Comment: Cool tutorial! I implemented my own ArrayAdapter according to the viewHolder Pattern. Now everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
v.setBackgroundResource(R.Color.GREEN);
```